# How do you convert from a level order tree to a preorder tree in R?

Tags: r, recursion, global-variables, tree-traversal

I have a list  which represents a tree being traversed in level order.

The first digit is the number of children and the second is its "level", starting at 1.

I want the program to output a list with the same elements as matr but in preorder instead.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Okr.png)

For the input:
list(c(4,1), c(0,2), c(2,2), c(0,2), c(1,2), c(0,3), c(0,3), c(0,3))

The output should be:
list(c(4,1), c(0,2), c(2,2), c(0,3), c(0,3), c(0,2), c(1,2), c(0,3))

I reckon the problem is with global variables? I've got it working in Python but not R when as far as I can see they are doing the same thing.

This is what I have:

```
matr = list(c(4,1), c(0,2), c(2,2), c(0,2), c(1,2), c(0,3), c(0,3), c(0,3))
tot = 3
new = list()

func <- function(new, matr, level,tot){
 if (level <= tot){
   for (i in 1:length(matr)){
     if (matr[[i]][2] == level){
       a = matr[[i]]
       matr = matr[-i]
       new = c(new, list(a))
       break
     }
   }
   if (a[1]!=0){
     for (i in 1:a[1]){
       func(new,matr,level+1,tot)
     }
   }
 }
}
func(new, matr,1,tot)
```

For reference, the following code does what I want it to (but it's in Python not R)

```py
matr = [[4,1], [0,2], [2,2], [0,2], [1,2], [0,3], [0,3], [0,3]]
tot=3
newm = []
def func(newm, matr, level):
    if level <= tot:
        a = [k for k in matr if k[1] == level][0]
        newm.append(a)
        matr.remove(a)
        for i in range(a[0]):
            func(newm,matr,level+1)
func(newm, matr,1)
print(newm)
```

Comment: The expected output would be:
list(c(4,1), c(0,2), c(2,2), c(0,3), c(0,3), c(0,2), c(1,2),  c(0,3))

Comment: I have included another image in the question which I hope makes it clearer what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind -- solved it

```
if (level<=tot){
  for(i in 1:length(matr)){
    if (matr[[i]][2]==level){
      a = matr[[i]]
      assign("matr",matr[-i], envir=.GlobalEnv)
      break
    }
  }
  
  assign("newm", c(newm, list(a)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  if (a[1]!=0){
    for (i in 1:a[1]){
      topreorder(level+1)
    }
  }
  
}
```